# Disabling GUI Texture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a gui texture that fit in my entire screen and a script attached to it. whenever i press on the screen (on the guitexture) , a projectile is launched based on the mouse position. The problem is that i put a pause button and when i press on it a projectile is launched before the game is paused. the script of the guitexture uses the OnMouseDown() method and the pause button uses the OnGui() method. Please Help ! I tried to use booleans but it didn't work. it seems like the two methods are being called at the same time.

Comment: If you go **Edit > Project Settings > Script Execution Order** and put your pause/gui script above/before your projectile script (or at least before the Default Time), does this solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my game, might not be the best solution, but worked very well for me.

The pause button was at the top of the screen on the left, so when touching/clicking on the screen, I tested the clicked area to the same as the button was, in the end it will only trigger the "click" effect if it is outside the pause button area.

It would get harder if you need more buttons, but this is just what worked for me, I hope it can help you.

Note: Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) works for mouse clicks and touches (android/iphone).

C#:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {                
        var buttonPos = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        if (!buttonPos.Contains(new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Screen.height - Input.mousePosition.y)))
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }
```